# Twig template can not find id : "Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id")

Tags: symfony, twig

I can not find the reason for the error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "event_show".") in MeetingBundle:Event:ev_index.html.twig at line 25.

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2_27\src\MeetingBundle\Controller\EventController.php

```
/**
 * Event controller.
 *
 * @Route("/event")
 */
class EventController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Event entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="event_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template("MeetingBundle:Event:ev_index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('MeetingBundle:Event')->findAll();

        dump($entities); //there are 19 lines in the table

        return array(
            'events' => $entities,
        );
    }
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2_27\src\MeetingBundle\Resources\views\event\ev_index.html.twig

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>Event list</h1>
    <table>

            {# empty array evaluates to false, http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html #}
    {% if events is not null %}
        {% for event in events %}
            <tr>
                {% if event.id is not null %}  
                    <td><a href="{{ path('event_show', { 'event_id': event.id }) }}">{{ event.id }}</a></td> 
                {% endif %}

                <td>{{ event.title }} </td>
...
       {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Function dump result is :

```
array:19 [▼
  0 => Event {#1212 ▼
    -id: 1
    -title: "title1"
    -keywords: ""
    -starttime: DateTime {#1209 ▶}
    -endtime: null
    -details: null
    -address: ""
    #latitude: null
    #longitude: null
    #street: null
    #number: null
    #city: null
    #country: null
    #state: null
    #zip: null
    #admins: PersistentCollection {#1219 ▶}
    #attendees: PersistentCollection {#1232 ▶}
    #comments: PersistentCollection {#1275 ▶}
  }
  1 => Event {#1278 ▶}
  2 => Event {#1286 ▶}
  3 => Event {#1294 ▶}
  4 => Event {#1302 ▶}
  5 => Event {#1310 ▶}
  6 => Event {#1318 ▶}
  7 => Event {#1326 ▶}
  8 => Event {#1334 ▶}
  9 => Event {#1342 ▶}
  10 => Event {#1350 ▶}
  11 => Event {#1358 ▶}
  12 => Event {#1366 ▶}
  13 => Event {#1374 ▶}
  14 => Event {#1382 ▶}
  15 => Event {#1390 ▶}
  16 => Event {#1398 ▶}
  17 => Event {#1406 ▶}
  18 => Event {#1414 ▶}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is about the `id` variable instead of `event_id`. Probably a typo so try this:

```
                <td><a href="{{ path('event_show', { 'id': event.id }) }}">{{ event.id }}</a></td>
```

instead of this:

```
                <td><a href="{{ path('event_show', { 'event_id': event.id }) }}">{{ event.id }}</a></td>
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was simple.

There is not `event_id` parameter in show action. I should use `id` instead.

Instead of

```
<td><a href="{{ path('event_show', { 'event_id': event.id }) }}">{{ event.id }}</a></td>
```

there must be:

```
<td><a href="{{ path('event_show', { 'id': event.id }) }}">{{ event.id }}</a></td>`
```

because event_show path is for the  `public function showAction($id)`.